# How to disable a DevExpress MVC combobox from the client (JS / JQuery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am attempting to disable a form based on an event.  I have a JQuery script that will disable all inputs for a table / div etc. however the DevExpress combobox still allows users to select an option.  The input portion of the control shows disabled, however the select button and dropdown are still functional.

Being new to the DevExpress client API and Jquery, my question is: How can I set the control to disabled using JQuery in a way that is cross browser compatible?

Here is what i currently Have

// JQuery Code

```
// Disable all input types in the table
$('#addressTable :input').attr('disabled', true);

// Disable DevExpress MVC Combobox  **(Fails)**
$('#StateProvinceType.StateProvinceTypeId').SetEnabled(false);
```

//HTML Extension Code

```
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(settings =>
{
   settings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDown;
   settings.Name = "StateProvinceType.StateProvinceTypeId";
   settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(int);
}).BindList(Model.States).GetHtml()
```

Comment: Use the Name property to get a direct access to the client-side programmatic object (not the ID selector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the **Name** / **ClientInstanceName** property is separated by dot, it is necessary to retrieve it from the "window" object via the "**ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName()**" method (due to the JavaScript specifics). Do not forget to enable the client-side API:

```
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(settings => {
    settings.Name = "StateProvinceType.StateProvinceTypeId";

    settings.Properties.Items.Add("1", "1");
    settings.Properties.Items.Add("2", "2");
    settings.Properties.Items.Add("3", "3");

    settings.Properties.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
}).GetHtml()

<input type="button" onclick="OnClick();" value="Toggle" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var enabled = true;

    function OnClick() {
        var comboBox = ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName("StateProvinceType.StateProvinceTypeId");
        comboBox.SetEnabled(!enabled);
        enabled = !enabled;
    }
</script>
```

Otherwise, the client-side programmatic object is available directly in the global context:

```
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(settings => {
    settings.Name = "comboBox";

    settings.Properties.Items.Add("1", "1");
    settings.Properties.Items.Add("2", "2");
    settings.Properties.Items.Add("3", "3");

    settings.Properties.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
}).GetHtml()

<input type="button" onclick="OnClick();" value="Toggle" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var enabled = true;

    function OnClick() {
        comboBox.SetEnabled(!enabled);
        enabled = !enabled;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That works and is exactly what I needed.  I also appreciated the distinction between simple and complex objects, a well formulated and written response, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When the id's have a dot, you need to use double backslash. So you need to change:

```
$('#StateProvinceType.StateProvinceTypeId')
```

For:

```
$('#StateProvinceType\\.StateProvinceTypeId')
```